# What is meant by Hostname and Application in SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, hostname, sql-server-profiler

Now I am trying SQL Server Profile. There new trace has been created and filter- `TextData like 'select%'`. It is running fine with output saved on SQL table.

I got required query. Beside I notice some rows have random alpha-numeric for ApplicationName and HostName(same data are given). Google explains like

1. what meant by those columns?
2. why this columns are used?

But my question is: 
why random alpha-numeric exist for ApplicationName and HostName?

```
select distinct top 5 ApplicationName,HostName from UploadDocInsert 
order by ApplicationName 


ApplicationName HostName
NULL            NULL        -- Trace start event 
00apymnvw4      aipjkkic0q
00db67a5h5      1fztcmcn5i
00doj84va4      st0mjhfqh0
00kob4z7lf      i7p379kbdb
```

[image: Reference imgae]

Edit 1:

```
select @@version 

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) 
    Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) <X64>
```

Note: This SQL Server is installed on Linux server.

Comment: On a side note - SQL Trace and Profiler are deprecated in favor of Extended Events.  Not sure what version of SQL Server you're using but your time would likely be better spent learning how to use Extended Events instead of Profiler.

Comment: Okay @squillman. I will try Extended Events. I updated question. Thanks.

Comment: *it as a replacement for SQL Server Profiler and Tracing.* from Google. Thanks @squillman for the point